# How do I add additional photos to my code in OpenCV Python for my Stitching Project?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

[image: log1][image: log2][image: log3]Honestly, I am pretty lost. I was finally able to stitch these two pictures together but am unsure on how to update my code to incorporate more than two photos. How would I change my code in order to allow for multiple picture stitchings? Below is what I have so far, and I should mention that the pictures I am using are low quality, so other simpler examples I found either did not work or could not use all of the pictures I needed. If someone could just give me a general direction on how I would begin to alter this code for up to five pictures, I would appreciate it.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

#sift is a feature descriptor that helps locate pixel coordinates i.e. corner detector
feature_extraction_algo = 'sift'

feature_to_match = 'bf'
#train image needs to be the one transformed
train_photo = cv2.imread('Stitching/Images/Log771/Log2.bmp')

#converting from BGR to RGB for Matplotlib
train_photo = cv2.cvtColor(train_photo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
train_photo_crop = train_photo[0:10000, 425:750]

#converting to gray scale
train_photo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(train_photo_crop, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)


#Do the same for the query image
query_photo = cv2.imread('Stitching/Images/Log771/Log3.bmp')
query_photo = cv2.cvtColor(query_photo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
query_photo_crop = query_photo[0:10000, 425:750]
query_photo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(query_photo_crop, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#crop both images



#view/plot images
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, constrained_layout=False, figsize=(16,9))
ax1.imshow(query_photo_crop, cmap="gray")
ax1.set_xlabel("Query Image", fontsize=14)

ax2.imshow(train_photo_crop, cmap="gray")
ax2.set_xlabel("Train Image", fontsize=14)
plt.savefig("./"+'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, optimize=True, format='jpeg')
plt.show()

#sift.detectAndCompute() gets keypoints and descriptors--helps to determine how similar or different keypoints are-- ie. one picture is 
#huge and one is small. Keypoints match but are not similar enough, which is where descriptors come in. 
#to compare the keypoints in vector format

def select_descriptor_methods(image, method=None):
    assert method is not None, "Please define a feature descriptor method. accepted Values are: 'sift, 'surf'"
    if method == 'sift':
        descriptor = cv2.SIFT_create()
    elif method == 'surf':
        descriptor = cv2.SURF_create()
    elif method == 'brisk':
        descriptor = cv2.BRISK_create() 
    elif method =='orb':
        descriptor = cv2.ORB_create()
    (keypoints, features) = descriptor.detectAndCompute (image, None)
    return (keypoints, features)

keypoints_train_img, features_train_img = select_descriptor_methods(train_photo_gray, method=feature_extraction_algo)

keypoints_query_img, features_query_img = select_descriptor_methods(query_photo_gray, method=feature_extraction_algo)

for keypoint in keypoints_query_img:
    x,y = keypoint.pt
    size = keypoint.size 
    orientation = keypoint.angle
    response = keypoint.response 
    octave = keypoint.octave
    class_id = keypoint.class_id
print (x,y)
 
print(size)

print(orientation)

print(response)
print(octave)
print(class_id)


print(len(keypoints_query_img))
features_query_img.shape
#Noting a basic fact that - SIFT descriptor is computed for every key-point detected in the image. 
#Before computing descriptor, you probably used a detector (as Harris, Sift or Surf Detector) to detect points of interest. Detecting key-points and computing descriptors are two independent steps!

#drawing keypoints using drawKeypoints(input image, 
# keypoints, output image, color, flag) -- keypoints based off input picture
#Displaying keypoints and features on both detected images
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20,8), constrained_layout=False)
ax1.imshow(cv2.drawKeypoints(train_photo_gray, keypoints_query_img, None, color=(0,255,0)))
ax1.set_xlabel("(a)", fontsize=14)
ax2.imshow(cv2.drawKeypoints(query_photo_gray, keypoints_query_img,None,color=(0,255,0)))
ax2.set_xlabel("(b)", fontsize=14)
plt.savefig("./Stitching/" + feature_extraction_algo + "Images" + '.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, optimize=True, format='jpg')
plt.show()

def create_matching_object(method,crossCheck):
    "Create and return a Matcher Object"
    
    # For BF matcher, first we have to create the BFMatcher object using cv2.BFMatcher(). 
    # It takes two optional params. 
    # normType - It specifies the distance measurement
    # crossCheck - which is false by default. If it is true, Matcher returns only those matches 
    # with value (i,j) such that i-th descriptor in set A has j-th descriptor in set B as the best match 
    # and vice-versa. 
    if method == 'sift' or method == 'surf':
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=crossCheck)
    elif method == 'orb' or method == 'brisk':
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=crossCheck)
    return bf

def key_points_matching(features_train_img, features_query_img, method):
    bf = create_matching_object(method, crossCheck=True)
        
    # Match descriptors.
    best_matches = bf.match(features_train_img,features_query_img)
    
    # Sort the features in order of distance.
    # The points with small distance (more similarity) are ordered first in the vector
    rawMatches = sorted(best_matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
    print("Raw matches with Brute force):", len(rawMatches))
    return rawMatches

def key_points_matching_KNN(features_train_img, features_query_img, ratio, method):
    bf = create_matching_object(method, crossCheck=False)
    # compute the raw matches and initialize the list of actual matches
    rawMatches = bf.knnMatch(features_train_img, features_query_img, k=2)
    print("Raw matches (knn):", len(rawMatches))
    matches = []
#loop over raw matches
    for m,n in rawMatches:
        # ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each
        # other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
        if m.distance < n.distance * ratio:
            matches.append(m)
    return matches


print("Drawing: {} matched features Lines".format(feature_to_match))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

if feature_to_match == 'bf':
    matches = key_points_matching(features_train_img, features_query_img, method=feature_extraction_algo)
    
    mapped_features_image = cv2.drawMatches(train_photo_crop,keypoints_train_img,query_photo_crop,keypoints_query_img,matches[:100],None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

# Now for cross checking draw the feature-mapping lines also with KNN
elif feature_to_match == 'knn':
    matches = key_points_matching_KNN(features_train_img, features_query_img, ratio=0.75, method=feature_extraction_algo)
    
    mapped_features_image_knn = cv2.drawMatches(train_photo_crop, keypoints_train_img, query_photo_crop, keypoints_query_img, np.random.choice(matches,50),None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    

plt.imshow(mapped_features_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("./Stitching/" + feature_to_match + "_matching_img_log_"+'.jpeg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, optimize=True, format='jpeg')
plt.show()
feature_to_match = 'knn'

print("Drawing: {} matched features Lines".format(feature_to_match))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

if feature_to_match == 'bf':
    matches = key_points_matching(features_train_img, features_query_img, method=feature_extraction_algo)
    
    mapped_features_image = cv2.drawMatches(train_photo_crop,keypoints_train_img,query_photo_crop,keypoints_query_img,matches[:100],
                           None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)

# Now for cross checking draw the feature-mapping lines also with KNN
elif feature_to_match == 'knn':
     matches = key_points_matching_KNN(features_train_img, features_query_img, ratio=0.75, method=feature_extraction_algo)
    
     mapped_features_image_knn = cv2.drawMatches(train_photo_crop, keypoints_train_img, query_photo_crop, keypoints_query_img, np.random.choice(matches,100),None,flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
    

plt.imshow(mapped_features_image_knn)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig("./Stitching/" + feature_to_match + "_Images"+'.jpg', bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, optimize=True, format='jpg')
plt.show()

def homography_stitching(keypoints_train_img, keypoints_query_img, matches, reprojThresh):
    
    keypoints_train_img = np.float32([keypoint.pt for keypoint in keypoints_train_img])
    keypoints_query_img = np.float32([keypoint.pt for keypoint in keypoints_query_img])
    
    ''' For findHomography() - I need to have an assumption of a minimum of correspondence points that are present between the 2 images. Here, I am assuming that Minimum Match Count to be 4 '''
    
    if len(matches) > 4:
    # construct the two sets of points
        points_train = np.float32([keypoints_train_img[m.queryIdx] for m in matches])
        points_query = np.float32([keypoints_query_img[m.trainIdx] for m in matches])
        
     # Calculate the homography between the sets of points
        (H, status) = cv2.findHomography(points_train, points_query, cv2.RANSAC, reprojThresh)

        return (matches, H, status)
    else: 
     return None
   
    
    
    
M = homography_stitching(keypoints_train_img, keypoints_query_img, matches, reprojThresh=4)

if M is None:
    print("Error!")

(matches, Homography_Matrix, status) = M

print(Homography_Matrix)

#Finally, we can apply our transformation by calling the cv2.warpPerspective function. The first parameter is our 
# original image that we want to warp, 
#the second is our transformation matrix M (which will be obtained from homography_stitching), 
#and the final parameter is a tuple, used to indicate the width and height of the output image.

# For the calculation of the width and height of the final horizontal panoramic images 
# I can just add the widths of the individual images and for the height
# I can take the max from the 2 individual images.

width = query_photo_crop.shape[1] + train_photo_crop.shape[1]
print("width ", width) 
# 2922 - Which is exactly the sum value of the width of 
# my train.jpg and query.jpg


height = max(query_photo_crop.shape[0], train_photo_crop.shape[0])

# otherwise, apply a perspective warp to stitch the images together

# Now just plug that "Homography_Matrix"  into cv::warpedPerspective and I shall have a warped image1 into image2 frame

result = cv2.warpPerspective(train_photo_crop, Homography_Matrix,  (width, height))

# The warpPerspective() function returns an image or video whose size is the same as the size of the original image or video. Hence set the pixels as per my query_photo

result[0:query_photo_crop.shape[0], 0:query_photo_crop.shape[1]] = query_photo_crop

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(result)

imageio.imwrite("./Stitching/Images/Log771/finishedLog"+'.jpg', result)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you really want to understand step by step whats happening in your stitching progress and where there might be problems the [stitching tutorial](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching_tutorial) might be worth a look

Comment: @lukasweber am looking through it now. I m excited because it has been hard to find a detailed example that uses more than two photos. The code is throwing errors in some places. For example, the 'from stitching.image_handler import ImageHandler' section is telling me that it is missing imports, but I can't find a download or anything that would resolve that issue.

Comment: You need to pip install stitching

Comment: @LukasWeber I got that downloaded and it did fix that issue. I'm trying to figure why FeatureDetector is not working. I tried installing a couple of packages such as Detecto with no luck.

Comment: Maybe open an issue in the repo and add sample images

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple method:

OpenCV makes it easy for you with the help of `cv2.Stitcher_create` module. Everything is handled internally, right from **identifying key feature points** to **matching them** appropriately and finally **warping** the images. You can pass in more than 2 images to be stitched. But I must warn you the greater the number of images and/or their dimensions; the greater the time needed for computation.

**How to use `cv2.Stitcher_create` module?**

First, we need to create an instance of the class.

`imageStitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create()`

To get a list of all the functions associated with this class just type `help(imageStitcher)`. It will return a list of all the functions along with its required input parameters and expected output.

The created instance contains a function `stitch()` which is used to create the panorama. `stitch` can be used in either of the following two ways:

1. `ret, panorama_image = stitch(images)`:

Pass the list of all the images and the module identifies key features, matches them and yields the warped image

2. `ret, panorama_image = stitch(images, masks)`:

Optionally, we can also pass a list of masks, with one mask corresponding to every image. A mask is a binary image comprising of black and white. The module looks for keypoints/features only in the white regions of every mask, proceeds to match them and yields the warped image.

Both the above ways also returns a variable `ret`, if the value is `0` it means stitching was performed without any issues.

The following code sample (which I borrowed) shows the first method:

**Sample images to be stitched:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import os
import cv2

# path containing images to be stitched
path = 'stitching_images'

# append all the images within the path to a list
images = []
for image_file in os.listdir(path):
  if image_file.endswith ('.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, image_file))
    images.append(img)

# creating instance of stitcher class
imageStitcher = cv2.Stitcher_create()

# call the 'stitch' function and pass in the list of images
status, stitched_img = imageStitcher.stitch(images)

# display the panorama if stitching is successful
if status = 0:
    cv2.imshow('Panorama', stitched_img)
```

**Result:**

[image]

*(Code and images borrowed from https://github.com/niconielsen32/ComputerVision/tree/master/imageStitching)*

#### Hard method:

If you want to create a panorama using your code, I would suggest performing it sequentially:

- Iterate through all the images in your collection (say A, B, C, D, E)
- For each pair of images, find keypoints and match them. (AB, AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, etc..)
- Select the pair where keypoint matches are the highest and stitch them using homography (say images A and C are warped to P1)
- Next find keypoint matches between the stitched image and every other image in your collection (P1B, P1D, P1E)
- Find the pair with most number of matches and stitch them
- Repeat likewise

Comment: For some reason, probably having to do with the pictures I am using, nothing happens when I execute that code. I had tried it before as well but it does not give me an error or anything. Do you know of where I can find an online example that uses the hard method you suggested?

Comment: @villasenorbritt Can you share a few images? Regarding the hard method, you already a set of functions you can extend them to incorporate what I have said. Please remember this was an idea of the top of my head

Comment: I have added in some pictures. I have had a hard time figuring out how to extend the functions. And I understand, I appreciate your input greatly.

Comment: If I add my updated code file, will you look it over and tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to match but keep getting errors

Comment: @villasenorbritt I would suggest opening a new question, it would get many more views. Make sure you add what changes you made